How can I get the first index of a mask and get None if the condtion does not met?
This is my DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1],
    }
)

My mask is:
mask = (df.a.gt(2))

And the expectet output is 4. The index of mask.
I can get it like this but if there are no values that met the condition it gives me an error. I want to get None if nothing found.
x = df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask].index[0]


You could slice and use first_valid_index:
out = df[mask].first_valid_index()

# or
# out = df.loc[mask, 'a'].first_valid_index()

Output: 4
Output with mask = df['a'].gt(10): None
Alternatively with idxmax and any:
out = mask.idxmax() if mask.any() else None

Or a pure python approach:
out = next((i for i,m in zip(df.index, mask) if m), None)

# alternatively (thanks @ChrisFu)
# out = next((i for i,m in mask.items() if m), None)

This is actually faster than vectorization if the DataFrame is large and the first True index occurs very early.
Timings
If the first True occurs early (df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(1_000_000)}) ; mask = df['a'].gt(2)):
# df.loc[mask, 'a'].first_valid_index()
5.26 ms ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# mask.idxmax() if mask.any() else None
17 µs ± 261 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

# next((i for i,m in zip(df.index, mask) if m), None)
2.69 µs ± 11.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

If the first True occurs late (mask = df['a'].ge(999_999)):
# df.loc[mask, 'a'].first_valid_index()
426 µs ± 21.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# mask.idxmax() if mask.any() else None
78.4 µs ± 142 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# next((i for i,m in zip(df.index, mask) if m), None)
91.6 ms ± 1.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Graph of timing depending on the position of the first True for an input of 1M rows:

Overall, using mask.idxmax() if mask.any() else None seems the best tradeoff.

Just for fun, a pure python approach: out = next((i for i,m in zip(df.index, mask) if m), None). This might actually be faster than vectorization if the DataFrame is large and the first True index occurs very early.

zip(df.index, mask) could be replaced with mask.items().

@ChrisFu that's true, thanks ;) I also added timings (zip or items is very similar)

x = mask.idxmax() if mask.any() else None


If a value is found from the mask it has a True value you could use this to filter masks where no value is found by using -
x = None if True not in mask else df.loc[mask.cumsum().eq(1) & mask].index[0]


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
df = pd.DataFrame(
   {
    'a': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1],
   }
)
mask = (df.a.gt(2))
def find_indices(lst, condition):
   return [i for i, elem in enumerate(lst) if condition(elem)]

find_indices(mask, lambda e: e == True)

